# Amfphp 2.2 Serializer mysqli_result

Tags: php, amfphp

try fix this problem all day and not find the solution...

Somebody help me?

```
[18-Jul-2014 17:13:11 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Amfphp_Core_Exception' with message 'Undefined property: mysqli_result::$1 . 
file:  /www/mysaas_teste/amfphp/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Serializer.php 
line: 911 
context: Array
(
    [d] => mysqli_result Object
        (
            [current_field] => 0
            [field_count] => 14
            [lengths] => 
            [num_rows] => 2
            [type] => 0
        )

    [explicitTypeField] => _explicitType
    [className] => mysqli_result
    [propertyNames] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [traitsInfo] => Array
        (
            [referenceId] => 0
            [propertyNames] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [key] => 1
    [value] => Array
        (
            [perfil] => 1
            [tela] => abertura_turno
            [funcao] => VISUALIZAR
            [acesso] => 1
            [data_inc] => 2014-05-28
            [hora_inc] => 16:20:35
            [user_inc] => 
            [data_alt] => 
     in /www/mysaas_teste/amfphp/Amfphp/Plugins/AmfphpErrorHandler/AmfphpErrorHandler.php on line 42
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you're returning the mysqli result set directly? You can't do that, you need to transform it into an array. My suggestion (and best practice, I think) is not to use mysqli directly but PDO which provides a handy abstraction layer for manipulating databases
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php